# Google-OR tools vs Pyomo and other commercial Solvers for solving a simple maximum flow problem

Tags: combinatorial-optimization, pyomo, or-tools, network-flow, cplex-python-api

I have implemented a Pyomo model for solving maximum flow problem as a subroutine of an algorithm. However, the approach does not scale very well because Pyomo does not provide a very good way to re-optimize the computation based on previous computations. (It provides a warm start but It does not seem to allow one to obtain the solution from the results and feed it in a following computation, therefore it is rather limited in this sense)

Google-OR tools provides an surprisingly easy way to solve maximum flow problems and claim it is also very performant https://developers.google.com/optimization/flow/maxflow

How well does this solver perform compared to other tools such as CPLEX and Gurobi and will it be a better option to consider than Pyomo?

Comment: I would suggest trying it out on your specific problem. Your problem may have different characteristics than some benchmark problem.

Comment: @SolverMax The specialized Max-FLow solver in ORTools that is being referred to, finds proven optimal solutions.  The statement *"It might not find an optimal solution"* makes no sense to me. I also very much doubt your claim about it being so slow.

Comment: Pyomo does provide a number of tools for re-optimizing a model based on previous computations. The best tool will depend on the change you're making to the model in between solves. Search for "Persistent Solvers" and "Auto-Persistent Pyomo Solver Interfaces" in the Pyomo read-the-docs pages.